# What's promonv1.0.vbs? Is it a virus?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, virus

I opened ccleaner and I saw this entry in the startup applications:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PromonV1.0.vbs
```

Looking into `C:\WINDOWS\System32\` that file doesn't exist. Is it a virus? I have AVG installed and fully updated but I haven't seen any warnings about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my search, it appears it was a virus, and is missing probably because your AV removed it....maybe AVG, or maybe some AV program you ran previously.

I would run HijackThis and if it shows those files in the list, but with "file missing" as part of the entry, it is safe to check them, and click "Fix checked". It is easier and safer to remove them this way if you don't really know what you are doing (although you may).

http://download.cnet.com/Trend-Micro-HijackThis/3000-8022_4-10227353.html

Comment: HijackThis didn't see it. Not sure what that means.

Comment: If it did not see it, that means that it is not trying to load anywhere, and that means you are all set.